# split row and column based given criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 8 rows and 50 columns. I want to split my data in the following format. How do I do it?

```r
R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6 R7 R8
1  2  3   4  5 6  7  8
1  2  3   4  5 6  7  8
1  2  3   4  5 6  7  8
1  2  3   4  5 6  7  8
1  2  3   4  5 6  7  8
```

I want to arrange the data as separate data frame for
r

```
R1 R2
1  2
1  2
1  2
1  2
1  2

R3, R4
#and So on.
```

In the end I should have data frame that has two columns and 5 rows of each data frame.

Comment: We can use `split.default`  `lst1 <- split.default(df1, as.integer(gl(ncol(df1), 2, ncol(df1))))`

Comment: Alternatively `lst1 <- lapply(seq(1, floor(ncol(df1)), 2), function(a) df1[,a:(a+1)])`

Comment: Thanks guys for the effort, but these script divides the dataframe into based on two columns, but i want database of two columns and 5 rows.All together i am expecting 15 dataframes, each data frame with 2 column and 5 rows.